# Why equaliser of product and terminal object is coproduct?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I’m reading “Sheaves in geometry and logic”, in page 80:

Please refer to [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/INrU0.jpg

It says “…,therefore $FU=\coprod_{x\in U} fx$. The space…”.

So could anyone please explain why therefore $FU$ is a coproduct?

It seems that $FU$ should be just the product of $F(\{x\})$?

Comment: It's a typo. The author was probably thinking about $Y$ and inverted the symbol.

Comment: Your guess is completely right, it must be $FU=\prod_{x\in U}fx$